# Unbound classpath container : 'JRE System Library in project 'HelloWorld'

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse + Java and trying to make my first HelloWorld project.
But I have this error message after creating the project.
I have read the many posts but it does not help me, because I do not even have a JRE installed in my Eclipse,
See my screenshot.
[image]

What can I do?
Where to find the JRE?
I have already installed the JDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you haven't installed any JRE - which is probably your problem.

Download the version (example [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) 1.8) from Oracle.

Then on Eclipse, try:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add
```

And follow the guide to your previously installed JRE.

Then go to:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Compiler compliance level
```

Ensure that matches the installed JDK.

Comment: I have changed the compiler level to 1.8 but it does not change anything...what to do next?

Comment: Does it still give the same error? If so, maybe clean/build and/or restart Eclipse and try again.

Comment: Made a clean and build, restarted Eclipse, and I still have the error

Comment: I have installed the JRE and it worked, thks. But what I don't understand is that I already had the JDK, which is supposed to contain already the JRE...

Answer (score 1):

1. In your screenshot click the ***Add...*** button
2. Select ***Standard VM*** and click <kbd>Next ></kbd>
3. Enter the installation directory of your Java 8 JRE (or better JDK) and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Comment: When I enter the installation directory (JDK directory) I get an error message saying "Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found."

Comment: On my system it is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`. Which directory did you choose for _JRE home_ in the _Add JRE_ dialog?